# Enable syntax highlighting in CMake project for Qt keywords

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

Here a screenshot to illistrate my problem. Qt Creator highlight qt specific keywords as invalid in CMake project. I use Qt Creator 4.2.2 and Fedora 26.

[image: signals and public slots are wrong but must be highlighted as correct]

I tried to use system syntax highlight defenition files and provided by Qt. But it doesn't help me. So how to fix this?

CMake code:

```
project("highlight-cmake")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

set(HEADERS
    mainwindow.h
)

set(SOURCES
    mainwindow.cpp
    main.cpp
)

set(FORMS
    mainwindow.ui
)

qt5_wrap_cpp(MOC_SOURCES ${HEADERS})
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_SOURCES ${FORMS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${MOC_SOURCES} ${UI_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` define set. This causes Qt keywords like `slots` and `signals` to be undefined. Either undefine `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` or use `Q_SLOTS` instead of `slots` and `Q_SIGNALS` instead of `signals`.

Comment: QT_NO_KEYWORDS is not set. I improved my question and add CMake code. Anyway I checked real command in compilation time.